# Obtaining land surface temperature in Google Earth Engine using GEET and TOA error is showing

Tags: google-earth-engine, expression, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am very new to using GEE and only using for one unit I'm currently doing (only using for two months and I have no coding experience). I am trying to calculate the land surface temperature estimate and I found a code from E. Lacerda but the only thing is that I get an error saying
"band_to_toa.expression is not a function
in toa_radiance(), line 938
..."
I've spent past  few hours trying to get my way around this by googling but nothing was useful for me. I'm really not sure what to do at this point and really trying to get this done asap for due dates.

Here's the link to my script
https://code.earthengine.google.com/14a01e61105994465263d252f0c501a1

```
var raw = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA") 
  .filterDate ('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31');

var surf_temp = function(image) {
  var geet = require('users/elacerda/geet:geet');
  var new_toa_radiance = geet.toa_radiance(raw, 11);
  var brightness = geet.brightness_temp_l8c(new_toa_radiance, true);
  var ndvi = geet.ndvi_l8(brightness);
  var veg = geet.prop_veg(ndvi);
  var lse = geet.surface_emissivity(veg);
  var surface = geet.surface_temperature_oli(lse);
  var lst = surface.select('LST');
  var img = lst
  return img;

};
Map.addLayer(raw.map(surf_temp));
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please do not include chit chat like greetings, statements of appreciation/thanks, etc - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0):

There is no call to `Image.expression` in your code, so it must be in `users/elacerda/geet:geet`. (When you're asking a question, please try to make sure that you're showing the problematic code *in your question*, not just referenced from it.)

We can *guess* that the problem is that you're not supplying the right type of object, so the method is not found, and indeed if I change

```js
var new_toa_radiance = geet.toa_radiance(raw, 11);
```

to

```js
var new_toa_radiance = geet.toa_radiance(image, 11);
```

then there is no error. Whether that computes what you want, I don't know.

You'll also need to set visualization parameters so the image isn't displayed as all black:

```
Map.addLayer(raw.map(surf_temp), {min: -115, max: -113});
```